# visual programming

Tags: c++, visual-c++

sir i have written a simple program to display a message box in visual c++ 2008 but the problem is that when i run this code a dialog box shows that "your project is out of date would  you like to build it"
when i press yes it shows error 
so what is the problem???
the code is here

```
#include <Windows.h>  /* The standard "windows.h" inclusion */

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,        /* A handle to the current instance of the application. */
  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,    /* A handle to the previous instance of the application. */
  LPSTR lpCmdLine,            /* The command line for the application, excluding the program name. */
  int nCmdShow)               /* Controls how the window is to be shown. */
{  
  /* Call to the MessageBox function */
  MessageBox(NULL, "Hello, Windows API!", "Hello", MB_OK);

  /* WinMain returns 0 if we exit before we enter message loop, more on that to come */
  return 0;  
}
```

Whenever i run this in visuall c++ 2008 it says project out of date, do u want to build so i click yes but then it cant
down the bottom it says

1>Linking...
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main
1>C:\Documents and Settings*****\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\msg\Debug\msg.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings*****\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\msg\msg\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Wrath Lands - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Could you add the actual error message? This is a bit like saying "Something's wrong with my car, here's a photo, what's wrong?"

Comment: There is no problem, Visual C++ suggests that you build your project once again, and it will run it.

Comment: If you have your code on a network drive and aren't syncing local time it may think your executables are older than the source files.

Comment: Joachim lsaksson plz reply now

Answer (score 0):

VS creates UNICODE projects by default so macros like MessageBox evaluates to MessageBoxW which expects LPCWSTR arguments and not LPCSTR. Try change to: MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello, Windows API!"), _T("Hello"), MB_OK);

Comment: MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello, Windows API!"), _T("Hello"), MB_OK); i use this this but the problem not resolved

Answer (score 0):

The error message `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main` is important. It looks like you've created a console project but there is no `main()` function defined, hence the linker error.

When you create a new Visual Studio project as a `Win32 Console Application` it assumes the entry point to your program will be the normal C/C++ `main()` function and it links with the C/C++ library startup code. If you instead create a `Win32 Project` it assumes the entry point will be `WinMain()` and links with Windows application startup code.

To avoid this problem you should begin with a `Win32 Project`. To fix it after the fact you could try going into `Project Properties` -> `Linker` -> `System` and change the `SubSystem` option from `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` to `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`. Note that there may be other settings that should be changed as well so I suggest you just start fresh with a new `Win32 Project` instead.